# Scala Class that containing List

Tags: scala, list, class

I have a very basic and simple Scala question. For example, I have a java class like that

```
class Dataset{
   private List<Record> records;
   Dataset(){
       records = new ArrayList<Record>()
   }
   public void addItem(Record r){
       records.add(r)


      }
}
```

When I try to write same class in Scala, I encoutered with some error:

```
class RecordSet() {

  private var dataset:List[Record]
  def this(){
    dataset = new List[Record]
  }

  def addRecord(rd: Record)={
    dataset :+ rd
  }

}
```

I cannot declare a List variable like (  private var dataset:List[Record])
and cannot write a default constructor.

Comment: "I cannot declare" / "I cannot write" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `class RecordSet() {

  private var dataset: List[Record] = Nil;

  def addRecord(rd: Record)=dataset = dataset ::: List(rd)
}` I write code like that and everything is ok

Comment: "I encoutered with some error" – And what is the error? Where does it occur? What does it say? The error message should tell you what the problem is, and it should provide the exact location of where the error occurs. Since you don't tell us what the error is and where it occurs, there is no way to help you.

Comment: You're not writing what you think you're writing. Try working with something like `class Dataset(val records: mutable.MutableList[Record])`. And also perhaps try knocking out a few Scala tutorials online...

Comment: Your code in the comment is how it is written in Scala. Constructor is not written as a separate function normally, it is written as a class body, members are initialized (you can have unitialized members, but then you have to specify this: `val member: Type = _`).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you will replicate the Java code you mentioned in your question:

```
// defining Record so the code below compiles
case class Record() 

// Here is the Scala implementation
class RecordSet(private var dataset:List[Record]) {
    def addRecord(rd: Record)={
      dataset :+ rd
    }
  }
```

**Some explanation:**

In Scala, when you define a class, you have the ability to pass parameter to the class definition. eg: `class Foo(num:Int, descr:String)` Scala would automatically use the given parameter to create a primary constructor for you. So you can now instantiate the Foo, like so `new Foo(1, "One")`. This is different in Java where you have to explicitly define parameter accepting constructors.

You have to be aware that the parameter passed do not automatically become instance member of the class. Although if you want, you can tell Scala to make them instance member. There are various ways to do this, one way is to prefix the parameter with either `var` or `val`. For example `class Foo(val num:Int, val descr:String)` or `class Foo(var num:Int, var descr:String)`. The difference is that with `val`, the instance variable are immutable. With `var` they are mutable.

Also, by default the instance member Scala will generate would be public. That means they can be accessed directly from an instance of the object. For example:

```
val foo = new Foo(1, "One")
println(foo.num) // prints 1.
```

If you want them to be private, you add private keyword to the definition. So that would become:

```
class Foo(private var num:Int, private var desc:String)
```

The reason why your code fails to compile is you define a method called `this()` which is used to create multiple constructors. (and not to create a constructor that initiates a private field which is your intention judging from the Java code you shared). You can google for multiple constructors or auxiliary constructors to learn more about this.

Comment: You should not use `var dataset: List[Record]`, as then you are creating a new list each time you add an element. Instead you should use `val` and a mutable collection such as `val dataset: mutable.MutableList[Record]`.

Comment: `dataset :+ rd` will be creating a new List and the current collection won't be changed. Hence the new element will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

1. As dade told the issue in your code is that with `this` keyword you are actually creating an `auxilary` constructor which has some limitations like `the first line of your auxilary constructor must be another constructor (auxilary/primary)`. Hence you cannot use such a way to create a class.

   2. Also you can not write such lines in a scala concrete class `private var dataset:List[Record]` as it is considered as abstract (no definition provided).

Now with the code. Usually in Scala we don't prefer mutability because it introduces side-effects in our functions (which is not the functional way but as scala is not purely functional you can use mutability too).

In Scala way, the code should be something like this:

```
  class RecordSet(private val dataset:List[Record]) {
    def addRecord(rd: Record): RecordSet ={
      new RecordSet(dataset :+ rd)
    }
  }
```

Now with the above class there is no mutability. Whenever you are adding on an element to the dataset a new instance of RecordSet is being created. Hence no mutability.

However, if you have to use the same class reference in your application use your a mutable collection for your dataset like below:

```
  class RecordSet(private val dataset:ListBuffer[Record]) {

    def addRecord(rd: Record): ListBuffer[Record] ={
      dataset += rd
    }
  }
```

Above code will append the new record in the existing dataset with the same class reference.